# How do you set Linux ACL to default to a specific group with permissions?

Tags: linux, permissions, file-permissions, acl

So I have a directory: `www\` which looks as so:

```
[eugene@server ~]$ ll
total 0
drwxrwx---. 2 eugene eugene 57 Dec 10 16:04 www
```

I want to make it so all new files created in this directory will belong to the group `apache` **and** have the permissions `770`.

So I did:

```
[eugene@server ~]$ chgrp apache www/
[eugene@server ~]$ setfacl -Rm u:eugene:rwx,d:g:apache:rwx,d:o:--- www/
[eugene@server ~]$ ll
drwxrwx---+ 2 eugene apache 43 Dec 10 16:10 www
[eugene@server ~]$ echo 123 > www/test.txt
[eugene@server ~]$ ll www/
-rw-rw----+ 1 eugene eugene       4 Dec 10 16:11 test.txt
[eugene@server ~]$
```

As you an see `test.txt` was created without the expected group of `apache`. Nor was the `x` (execute) permission set...

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

In order files within your directory are created with apache group you'd better to set SETGUID bit:

```
chmod +2000 www
```

As for default rights to create files, you can not do it using ACL, because default Linux umask always win. Umask doesn't allow making files with any 7 digit (rwx) in the rights of created files.

Instead you can create a script **mkfile** with the following inside:

```
touch $1
chmod 770 $1
```

make it executable:

```
chmod 750 mkfile
```

and put it to /usr/local/bin folder.
Now you can create files with 770 permissions everywhere:

```
mkfile my_file
```